# How to get Canon ip110 printer error codes

Tags: printing, canon

This printer is installed automatically but it does not report the error codes that the printer sends when a problem occurs. How can i get the corresponding error codes? In the properties of the printer only appears  the message that the printer is offline or online. Nothing else.
Thank you

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: it is a driver in ubuntu, not a Canon driver.